# No tests found with test runner 'JUnit 4'

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, selenium-webdriver

Ao criar um novo pacote e dentro desse pacote  criar um novo teste ao tentar rodar o teste o eclipse retorna a  mensagem: "No tests found with test runner 'JUnit 4'"
Dentro do projeto eu tenho outro pacote com outros testes que rodam normalmente.

Alguém sabe me dizer o que fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Veja se existe pelo menos um método anotado com [@Test](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Test.html) na sua classe de teste.

Exemplo:

```
@Test
public void testFoo() {...}
```

Comment: O @Test só é suportado a partir da versão 4 do JUnit, então se for uma versão anterior não vai haver a anotação no método. É bom ver também se o projeto tem o JUnit 4 configurado nas dependências, já que ele está sendo executado com essa versão.